# Only Local ADLA account available after Visual Studio update

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I updated Visual Studio Professional 2017 from v15.2 to 15.3 and now the Submit menu only contains the (Local) ADLA account. I can access my ADLA accounts via Server Explorer, but I don't see them in the Submit menu in a U-SQL file. Why is that?

Comment: I reached out to the tools team to check. However, one thing I sometimes note is that an already existing open script file window will not get updated if a log-in occurs after it got opened. So I have to close it and reopen it. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. It was the Cloud Explorer that had filtered my subscriptions, as mentioned in Dian's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether you have subscription filtered in CloudExplorer.
Acount list shown in submit menu is based on filter configuration in CloudExplorer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got this going by:
 - Open cloud explorer
 - Click on the account management icon
 - [Make sure the subscriptions aren't filtered here as mentioned above]
 - Click on Manage Account link
 - Remove all accounts except the one containing the right subscription
 - OK that and re-open you script